# Fonts blurry on Google Chrome (tried various methods) after reinstallation

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

I reinstalled Windows yesterday on my laptop. Somehow, the fonts start to become blurry on Google Chrome. I do not know how to fix it. I tried various methods on the internet including disabling hardware acceleration, cleartext, chrome/flag etc, but to no avail.

I also noticed that if you do not sign in to Google account, the font is different when you sign in. This is really weird and caught me off guard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with you and tried similar methods and neither of them worked. It looks like Google is testing some new fonts on several accounts and its not a text rendering issue. After four days the font came back to normal for me. (Windows 7)